# Why am I Getting Incorrect Results When I use Math.Atan2

Tags: c#, math, atan2

The program takes two points to find the distance between the two points and find the angle to get from point one to point 2. The distance portion works fine but when I use Math.Atan2 to find the angle I get an inccorect answer.

```
    //these are the variables the store the points
    static float point1X = 2;
    static float point1Y = 2;
    static float point2X = 4;
    static float point2Y = 4;
    
    //This is the code I use to find the distance
    float deltaX = point1X - point2X;
    float deltaY = point1Y - point2Y;

    float step1 = MathF.Pow(deltaX, 2f) + MathF.Pow(deltaY, 2f);
    float distance = MathF.Sqrt(step1);

    //this is the code used to find the angle
    float radians = (float)Math.Atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
    float angle = radians * (float)(180 / Math.PI);

    Console.WriteLine(distance + " " + angle);
```

I tried the points (2,2)  and (4,4). The result I got for the angle was -135. I also tried the points (5,5) and (4,4) which yeilded 45.

Comment: Atan2 would typically return radians.  Did you convert these to degrees?  Please edit and show actual code call.  Also, typically, the input is one x and one y, which would presumably be the "delta" between the points, that I would interpret as +2/+2 should be first quadrant, so you should edit question and show how you are doing that as well.

Comment: Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to ask a question properly. You don't post pictures of code.

Comment: Yes, please write out the code as text with proper formatting.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you write `deltaX = point1X - point2X` then that delta is the signed distance starting at point 2 and ending at point 1. Your intuition is probably the opposite: start at 1 and end at 2. So you should swap that difference around. Same for *y*.

How many steps are there from 3 to 8? There are 8 - 3 = 5 steps. See, end minus start is what you'd use in everyday situations, too.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I tried it and it works the order was the issue!!